# How to solve Hoffman & Kunze exercise 5, section 10.2

Tags: linear-algebra

> Describe the bilinear forms on $R^3$ which satisfy $f(v,w)=-f(w,v) \forall v,w$.

I find it that these are the antisymmetric bilinear forms, so I just have to describe a 3x3 antisymmetric matrix given an ordered basis?

Or am I misinterpretating something?

Comment: Your interpretation sounds good.